# Draggable not applied to nested component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In

https://codesandbox.io/s/vskdf

I have a template that is not rendered inside of my [vuedraggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuedraggable). Any ideas why?

`InventorySectionGroup.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <!-- this div renders -->
  <div class="inventory-section-group">
    <p>{{ itemSectionGroupProps.itemSectionCategoryName }}</p>
    <div
      v-for="group in itemSectionGroupProps.itemSectionCategoryItemList"
      :key="group.itemSectionCategoryId"
    >
      <inventory-section-group-item :itemDataProps="group">
      </inventory-section-group-item>
    </div>
    <!-- div doesn't render :-(
      <draggable v-model="itemSectionGroupProps.itemSectionCategoryItemList">
      <transition-group>
        <div
          v-for="group in itemSectionGroupProps.itemSectionCategoryItemList"
          :key="group.itemSectionCategoryId"
        >
          <inventory-section-group-item :itemDataProps="group">
          </inventory-section-group-item>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
    </draggable> -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Fixed errors related to comp. init:

https://codesandbox.io/s/y2cur?file=/src/components/InventorySectionDraggable.vue

Nested dnd can be replicated like:

https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-perlman-n6psw?file=/src/components/MyContainer.vue

Comment: PS: you have a strange `-` package entry in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with nested draggable (build satellite data related to inventory groups and items):

https://codesandbox.io/s/x8ur4?file=/src/components/InventorySectionDraggable.vue

I still need to wrap the props around components.

Done:

https://codesandbox.io/s/rmh2n

Comment: @kissu there's still some work to be done :P

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your code (browser console + ESlint), try fixing them, this will highlight several issues that may be blocking at some point.

As for your current issue, you do have some duplicated code: the block that is rendered and the one that is not. This is coming from the fact that the `:key` needs to be **unique**. Since your code is the same on the 2 blocks, the key is duplicated and only one is rendered I guess.

If you take the second block with it's

```html
<div :key="group.itemSectionCategoryId">
```

And update it to some **naive** unique key like this

```html
<div :key="`${group.itemSectionCategoryId + 1}`">
```

This will render the 2 blocks as expected I guess.
Here is the end result.
[image]

Comment: Edited question with a fix related to errors; the problem is related to the data and how the template is being rendered. There are two containers that need to support dnd; categories and items; but each have different fields (including ids). When an item is rendered as a category it lacks category fields (e.g. `itemSectionCategoryName`).

Comment: @sebi faster to create a github repo if you're planning to push changes like this. Also, try to scope down. Looking at the code here, you need to have a `nested-draggable`: https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/nested-example DIdn't saw any in your code.

Comment: I'm trying to add it now but I've managed to reproduce nested draggable behavior without it: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-perlman-n6psw?file=/src/components/MyContainer.vue

Comment: I'm not sure that this is working totally as expected because you cannot have a depth > 2 (the `pre` is looking pretty ugly and hard to understand too). And I guess that if `vuedraggable` do have a `nested-draggable` component, there is a reason. Using some hacks won't make clean code at the end (and sometimes it just won't work at all) IMO.

Comment: A fixed depth is intentional; (in my case each category can have only one level of items). At this point, style matters less than functionality, these are rudimentary hacks meant to showcase reproducible behavior.

Comment: A bit of styling can help people understand a bit better your example. Everybody can share his own code, it's clear and simple for them because they wrote it. Taking a bit of time to make something more visual can greatly help showing the others what is not working. Because here, I'm not sure what is not working. If you want to have it with a fixed depth and if you're able to display them properly, it's fine so far no?

Comment: Drag and drop works only when dragging items within the same category (either `Books` or `Movies`) but not with the categories themselves (this is due to the different fields that each container has that mismatch directives). Moving elements from one category to another works only once but dragging them back or outside a category causes them to disappear (same reason). Styling can wait.

Comment: An example of 2 lists, should be what you're looking for so far: https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/two-lists

Comment: No, please reread the question. The linked to example provides no nesting. Moreover, this barebones example must be extended to vue components instead of static payloads.

Comment: The initial question is answered so far. If you want to edit it with further details (all of them), you can. You have 2 things: 2 different lists and having a 2-depth nested draggable object. Double-check all the examples and make a mix of both. Having a `.vue` component rather than a static payload should not be a blocker (or is it?). I do also think that fixing some of the errors, removing useless code (transitions and alike) and adding some style could help you debug it a bit easily. Having a lot of things at the same time will be hard to debug.

Comment: It does not work as expected (see comment above). Yes, cleaning up helps but it's not the main point.